# How to type a function that returns the single element in an array that lives in a property from an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have this function

```
function single<T, TElem, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, name: K): TElem {
  const source = obj[name];
  if (source.length !== 1) {
    throw Error(`Debería existir exactamente un ${name} asociado`);
  }
  return _.first(source);
}
```

The idea of the funcion is to return the unique value in an array that lives in the specified property in the original object. The thing is that i don't know how to type that function with something like this:

```
function single<T, TElem, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, name: K): TElem 
   where T[K] extends TElem[]
{
  const source = obj[name];
  if (source.length !== 1) {
    throw Error(`Debería existir exactamente un ${name} asociado`);
  }
  return _.first(source);
}
```

is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be inclined to use a typing like this:

```
function single<K extends PropertyKey, T extends Record<K, any[]>>(
  obj: T, 
  name: K
): T[K][number] {
    const source = obj[name];
    if (source.length !== 1) {
        throw Error(`Debería existir exactamente un ${name} asociado`);
    }
    return source[0];
}
```

So `name` is of some key-like `K`, and `obj` has to be a type `T` that has an array at its `name`-valued property.  And then the output type is `T[K][number]`; that's the type you get when you index into `T` with a property of type `K` and then index into that with a property of type `number`... meaning it's the type of, say, `obj[name][0]`.

Let's see if it works:

```
const obj = {
    a: [1],
    b: "not me",
    c: ["okay"],
};

const num = single(obj, "a");
num.toFixed();

const oops = single(obj, "b"); // error!
// ---------------> ~~~
// string is not compatible with any[]

const str = single(obj, "c"); // okay
str.toUpperCase();

const alsoOops = single(obj, "d"); // error!
// -------------------> ~~~
// prop "d" is missing in obj
```

Looks good to me.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZxmA5gGwKYB4DSi2AHlNmACbKIAKATnAA7Z1QCe+2bANIgCpFS5KogBK2CHDoUCvAIZg2AbQC6APjUAKOACMAVgC5+vMHIC22I-gCURvkvwqlYEGZ0sViAN4BYAFCIgYiSYMhQKHAgdBDYiAC8iLp6zubYKgDc-kGIMMCImsiR0dgAdDgYUAAWiACEcQkAjNbeWdlBVQwA7ogAonQMdJoABgAi2O50ALdygjBhMHSCctCpYGSI4IgAJF6mFgC+iHKFEDByFHBD1pkBQfutgXTYUFFIhVExSgAMGf73fv4QmFEvp4i1boE5EYlA0VNwHogdEYAERgODhCzI3gIiDQ5FwADWcjYyLhfxugIQwJcZjBqAwOG0+l4yLkyOu-hpJSgcAAYjBiNgKJoOQC-EDwnAmNQEvSsNgmXoWTp2elEAB6dVEfpSGr+TWIAC0xpNprNakQAD9rfqtWE6Gh0DlqGjwpIzIw5LAdDhEJ0YFUjopVP5KaFwva6Y7GUkWRBVRqtYTif57dy4ABVRjMOgAYWOCtFYeBckwhQA8tKowyFbHEMiKAmDSwBnq-AazZ2u4aLdbLbbEIwGIx643nYgzHM5TkkElQ34gA)